# I am trying to read from the input file then compare a specific part of a string using their substrings

Tags: c++

Let's say I am reading from a file then comparing the  7483289 in the code with any match in the file.

i ran the code the program crashed and terminated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file1;
    file1.open("input.txt");
    string str2 = str1.substr(12, 8); //comparing this
    string str3 = "Kennedy chewe 7483289 20174893 2017"; //with this
    string str4 = str2.substr(12, 8);

    if (file1.is_open())
    {
        while (!file1.eof())
        {
            getline(file1, str1);

            if (str2 == str4)
            {
                cout << "match!";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "In line " << str1 << " there is no a match of: " << str2 << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input file format

```
  Mark      Bwalya       2436586  20146438  2014
  Max       peter        7483289  20174893  2017
  Lisa      Phiri        3674765  20813672  2018
  Chitalu   Malama       4672762  20146437  2014
  Frank     Tambo        6546727  20016367  2001
  Malika    Chewe        4729208  20137346  2013
  Raymod    Daka         3894782  20157835  2018
  Lucy      Kalinga      5849535  20164675  2016
  Jack      Kakwekwe     7548394  20143757  2014
   Oka      gjriudf      6458934  20135743  2013
  Emmanucle Fuka         4325673  20137578  2013
  Brian     Mwale        5327834  20174673  2017
  Lisa      MWeka        1895865  20013647  2001
```

expected output if there is not a match of str4.

`In line  Mark Bwalya 2436586 20146438 2014 there is no a match of 7483289`

expected out if there is a match

`In line Max peter 7483289 20174893 2017 there is a match of 7483289`

< http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/270707/>

Answer (score 0):

The main root cause is, you are not considering spaces between words in your file. So, position "12" in str1 is NOT the start of integer, but it's somewhere around 20.

To make your problem very easy, you can use [string streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

It's just like you are reading from files, instead, you read from strings.
Here is the solution code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream file1;
  file1.open("input.txt");

  stringstream sstr3{"Kennedy chewe 7483289 20174893 2017"}; //Key string
  string key_name1, key_name2, key_num1, key_num2, key_num3;
  sstr3 >> key_name1 >> key_name2 >> key_num1 >> key_num2 >> key_num3;

  if(file1.is_open()) {
    while(!file1.eof()) {
      string str1;
      getline(file1, str1); //input string
      stringstream sstr2{str1};
      string name1, name2, num1, num2, num3;
      sstr2 >> name1 >> name2 >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
      if (num1 == key_num1) { //Comparison
        cout << "match!" << endl;
      }
      else {
        cout << "In line " << str1 << " there is no a match of: " << key_num1 << endl;
      }
    }
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,am having another problem here when built the code i got this [link]error: extended initializer lists only available with '-std=c++11' or '-std=gnu++11'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|[/link] what does it exactly mean?

Comment: Hey @RayMond, you are using older C++ version. In the same code, instead of {}, use () at initialization. Ex: ```stringstream sstr3("Kennedy chewe 7483289 20174893 2017");``` and ```stringstream sstr2(str1);```

Comment: i will as well upgrade the c++ vision